# Chrome back button (newly) steals page focus

Tags: google-chrome

Last night I updated to Chrome 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my Mac (Sierra).  I'm now seeing the following new behavior: after using the "back" button, the page I've gone back to doesn't have focus.  That is, if I use the arrow or page up/down or home/end keys to navigate the page, nothing happens.  I have to click in the page to get the focus again.

This doesn't happen when I navigate to a page via links; after the page load, these keys work as expected.  It's only when going back, and only with this update.  (I had 68.something before; apparently I skipped 69.)

I disabled user scripts and tried several sites -- Stack Exchange sites, XKCD, weather.com all behave this way.  I found something in searching that suggested it might have to do with iframes, so I tried on a bare-bones HTML page (hand-written) with nothing fancy going on, and it happens there too.

While waiting for Google to fix this, is there something I can do to force the page to have the correct focus?  If there targets within the page (such as a search box), ideally the focus would be wherever it would have been were that page freshly loaded instead of reached via "back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been driving me nuts as well. It doesn't happen when I use Command-Left Arrow to navigate back, instead of clicking on the back button. I also installed the [Go Back With Backspace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-back-with-backspace/eekailopagacbcdloonjhbiecobagjci/related?hl=en) extension, which lets me use the backspace key as a shortcut. (Another feature Chrome broke a while back.)

Comment: Thanks!  I never thought to try a keyboard shortcut.  I'll attempt to train myself to do that.

Comment: I think I used to use the keyboard, but untrained myself when they removed the backspace shortcut. Now I'm attempting to retrain myself to use the keyboard again.